# How to search words from txt file to python

Tags: python

How can I show words which length are 20 in a text file?

To show how to list all the word, I know I can use the following code:

```
#Program for searching words is in 20 words length in words.txt file
def main():
    file = open("words.txt","r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    for line in lines:
        print (line)
    return

main()
```

But I not sure how to focus and show all the words with 20 letters.

Big thanks

Answer (score 5):

If your lines have lines of text and not just a single word per line, you would first have to split them, which returns a list of the words:

```
words = line.split(' ')
```

Then you can iterate over each word in this list and check whether its length is 20.

```
for word in words:
    if len(word) == 20:
        # Do what you want to do here
```

If each line has a single word, you can just operate on `line` directly and skip the for loop. You may need to strip the trailing end-of-line character though, `word = line.strip('\n')`. If you just want to collect them all, you can do this:

```
words_longer_than_20 = []    
for word in words:
        if len(word) > 20:
            words_longer_than_20.append(word)
```

Comment: In my case, there are one word in one line

Comment: minor detail, OP only asked for words of length 20 :)

Comment: It's supposed to words with length equal to 20 rather than larger than 20.

Comment: Use `split()` without specifying a delimiter to remove and split by any kind of space including line break or tab. This will remove the need for `strip()`.

Answer (score 2):

If your file has one word only per line, and you want only the words with 20 letters you can simply use:

```
     with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
         words = f.read().splitlines()
         found = [x for x in words if len(x) == 20]
```

you can then print the list or print each word seperately

Comment: because f.readlines() reads new line character and gets counted as a letter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
f = open('file.txt')
new_file = f.read().splitlines()

words = [i for i in f if len(i) == 20]

f.close()
```

Comment: You should probably close the file as well.

Comment: Actually, any python file opening with a read(), readlines(), or splitlines() method does not have the attribute close(), and will give you an AttributeError. However, if the just opened the file for reading like this: f = open(filename), then f.close() is a valid operation.

Comment: That's not true. Once you opened a file, you need to close it. Otherwise, some implementation of python will keep the file open until the program will exist. This is a bad practice.

Comment: When opening a file for writing or appending, you must close the file when finished. However, when using readlines(), read(), or splitlines(), python will throw an Attribute Error.

Comment: The attribute error is because you trying to access the result of `splitlines()` which is a `list`. You didn't save the reference to the file so you can't close it, but you should! Please read the python documentation (or any other programming book actually).

Comment: I did not know about the reference to the file. How do you save its reference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144361/discussion-between-liran-funaro-and-ajax1234).